# In Star Trek: Birth of the Federation, why don't I gain science research from espionage?

Tags: star-trek-birth-of-the-federation

I have been playing *Star Trek: Birth of the Federation* for years now (still hooked) but not once have I ever gained any science research points from science specific espionage. Is there a reason for this? Is it just me or is this actually a bug in the program (or designed this way)? If so what is the purpose of actually using up intelligence points on science espionage?? I have gone through the manual many times and it implies that you can gain science research from intelligence but I just don't see how.

Comment: I envy you. I lost my CD years ago. One of the best 4X ever made.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a bug. To me it ought to be a feature, too.

Edit:
here is something I have found [in a guide](http://www.armadafleetcommand.com/botf/xavori-strategy-guide):

> Playing the Cardassians allows you to use espionage well. The
>   Cardassians are the only race that can actually gain more research
>   through espionage than doing it themselves. However, that requires a
>   significant investment in intelligence resources as well as a large
>   enough fleet to keep the targets from retaliating with force.

So I recommend on trying it with the Cardassians next time or try to patch your game, have fun :)

Comment: Welcome to Arqade!  Unfortunately, what you were linking to there is piracy.  Since we don't condone that in any way, I have removed your extra text.

Comment: sorry, didn't think it was important for a 15 years old game that no one has a cd from anymore >.< I had no evil thoughts at all. But ok I'll acceppt these terms for the future.

Comment: @user67288: Relative. [MicroProse had a turbulent history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MicroProse), but it was bought by [Atari](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atari) which now holds all the rights until the copyright expires (you can thank Disney for the long wait). Now as I just read, Atari is bankrupt. I'm not a lawyer, but if Atari manages to close their doors without selling their stuff, the copyright is effectively gone as the owning entity is gone...now, we'll have to wait for that, too. Or we could also ask Atari nicely if they abandon it before that...until then, we obey the laws.